# undefined method `resources' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am learning Ruby on Rails and trying to create a sample app. I have created the following files:

app/controllers/books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @books = Book.all
    end
end
```

app/models/book.rb

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do |map|
    map.resources :books
end
```

I am using ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]
and rails 5.0.0.1 versions.

Why I am getting error undefined method 'resources' for nil:NilClass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :books
end
```

Comment: I tried that but then when i launch application it shows you are on ruby page. I have books table created in sqlite3 with data in it.

Comment: add this inside `draw` block:
`root 'books#index`'